# .map is not a function Vercel Deploy

Tags: next.js, prisma, vercel

Normally if I get an error when using .map it's because the array on which I'm using the method either doesn't exist or isn't an array at all.

Sometimes I return a JSON object from a fetch and I try to use .map on the object instead of an array that's inside of the object.

These are rookie errors, and I am a rookie. However, in the following case I'm sure that I am calling the .map on an array that is inside of a JSON object.

How?

1. Because the following code *works locally in development* and
2. Because I console.log(albums) to make damn sure that I was iterating over an array.

When I deploy this next.js app on Vercel, I get the following error:

```
> Build error occurred
21:23:30    TypeError: albums.map is not a function
21:23:30        at getStaticPaths (/vercel/workpath0/.next/serverless/pages/albums/[id].js:306:16)
21:23:30        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
21:23:30        at async buildStaticPaths (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:16:80)
21:23:30        at async Object.isPageStatic (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:23:549) {
21:23:30      type: 'TypeError'
21:23:30    }
21:23:30    error Command failed with exit code 1.
21:23:30    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
21:23:30    Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
21:23:32    Done with "package.json"
```

Here's the page this error is referring to:

```
import React from "react";
import { useQuery, useMutation, useQueryClient } from "react-query";
import Image from "next/image";
import { queryAlbum } from "../../api/albums/[id]";
import { queryAlbums } from "../../api/albums";
import Form from "../../../components/styles/Form";
import Button from "../../../components/styles/Button";
import Container from "../../../components/styles/AlbumsShow";

async function createPicture(pictureData) {
  const response = await fetch(`/api/pictures/create`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(pictureData),
  });
  const { picture } = response.json();
  return picture;
}

async function deletePicture(pictureId) {
  await fetch(`/api/pictures/delete`, {
    method: "DELETE",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(pictureId),
  });
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const albums = queryAlbums();
  const paths = [];
  await albums.map((album) => {
    return paths.push({
      params: {
        id: album.id.toString(),
      },
    });
  });
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const response = await queryAlbum(params.id);
  const data = await JSON.stringify(response);
  const initialAlbumData = await JSON.parse(data);
  return {
    props: {
      initialAlbumData,
    },
  };
}

export default function Album({ initialAlbumData }) {
 ...all the code for the component 
  );
}
```

and here are the query functions:

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

export async function queryAlbum(albumId) {
  const prisma = new PrismaClient({ log: ["query"] });

  try {
    const album = await prisma.album.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: parseInt(albumId),
      },
      include: {
        pictures: true,
      },
    });
    return album;
  } catch (error) {
    return { error: error };
  } finally {
    prisma.$disconnect();
  }
}

export default async function answerQuery(req, res) {
  // get [id] from url
  const {
    query: { id },
  } = req;
  const album = await queryAlbum(id);
  res.json({ album: album });
}
```

and:

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

export async function queryAlbums() {
  const prisma = new PrismaClient({ log: ["query"] });

  try {
    const albums = await prisma.album.findMany();
    return albums;
  } catch (error) {
    return { error: error };
  } finally {
    prisma.$disconnect();
  }
}

export default async function Albums(req, res) {
  const albums = await queryAlbums();
  res.json({ albums: albums });
}
```

For a little context on why I chose to import queryAlbum and queryAlbums, here's a thread on Git that I used to base my code on:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13648

Comment: I think, api under `/api/` should be called as service, you are calling as method

Comment: You `const albums = await queryAlbums();` is might not be getting the proper data, Just check what is the response from that line

Comment: @Swaraj Gandhi Thank you for the suggestion. When I console.log(albums), it returns an array of albums.

Comment: It might be nothing, but await generally shouldn't be used on non-async functions. `.map` is synchronous

Comment: @Yaakov Ainspan I agree. In fact, I only added 'await' after I exhausted other options and I just began trying things willy-nilly. The code above works without 'await' in front of .map as well.

Comment: Maybe try cloning the array into a new one: `const _albums = [...albums];`

Comment: @Yaakov Ainspan I tried cloning the array and got this error when I deployed it to Vercel
TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Comment: Can you run it locally and put the result here? Also, is there are any environment configuration that has to be done to ensure that it isn't returning an error?

Comment: @Yaakov Ainspan Sure! What exactly would you like to see?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem in two steps.

First, I found an answer on Git: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8041. Basically, all I needed to do was delete the "babel" configurations. I really don't know why this answer works. I'll look into it and post updates here.

package.json that causes the error on deploy:

```
{
  "name": "photo_album",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prisma": "prisma",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^2.13.1",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.12.0",
    "next": "10.0.3",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-query": "^3.5.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@prisma/cli": "^2.13.1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "env": {
      "development": {
        "presets": [
          "next/babel",
          "@babel/preset-react"
          "next/babel"
        ],
        "plugins": [
          [
```

the answer:

```
{
  "name": "photo_album",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prisma": "prisma",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p $PORT",
    "postinstall": "prisma generate",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^2.13.1",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.12.0",
    "next": "10.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-query": "^3.5.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "@prisma/cli": "^2.13.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "@prisma/cli": "^2.13.1"
  }
}
```

The second step involved changing getStaticProps to getServerSideProps and DELETING getStaticPaths.
Here's what getServerSideProps looks like:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const response = await queryAlbum(context.query.id);
  const data = await JSON.stringify(response);
  const initialAlbumData = await JSON.parse(data);

  if (!initialAlbumData) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {
      initialAlbumData,
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the import, seems these are api you created. These are not normal methods, they are http methods, can be consume over http(http call).

```
import { queryAlbum } from "../../api/albums/[id]";
import { queryAlbums } from "../../api/albums";
```

I am using `fetch` to consume respective apis.

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const data = await fetch('/api/albums');
  const albums = await data.json();
  const paths = await albums.map((album) => {
    return paths.push({
      params: {
        id: album.id.toString(),
      },
    });
  });
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const response = await fetch(`/api/albums/${params.id}`);
  const data = await response.json();
  return {
    props: {
      initialAlbumData: data,
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: I really like this suggestion. However, next.js won't accept relative paths in getStatisPaths()

Comment: have you tried? i can see you used other api `/api/pictures/create`, does it work?

Comment: Yes. And unfortunately, next.js won't accept relative paths in getStaticPaths or getStaticProps. It will allow for relative paths in the other functions I've written

Comment: You are right.. can you share `queryAlbums` and `queryAlbum` code?

Comment: Sure! I just posted them

Comment: my understanding: its a pure static site. With apollo server running remotely, you build the app with `next build` and `next export` commands. you test it locally and it works. Then when do the same thing  in Vercel, build fails and it could not get deployed. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I haven't used ```next build``` or ```next export``` to test my program locally. I don't know what those commands do. Out of the box, a program built with next.js runs on localhost:3000. So, I tested my app on localhost. When I deploy to Vercel, it runs ```next build```. When it does, the deployment fails with the error I posted to this post